# Batch copy and rename with regexp

Tags: rename, cp

I am wondering whether there is a way how to copy and rename a bunch of files without scripting. I have files with names like `prefix_12345678901_12345678901_suffix.ext` and I need to copy all of them into a given directory such that the copies are named like `1234567890_1234567890.ext`

I also do not want to overwrite existing files in the target directory.

I know I could do something like:

```
cp -n source/*.ext target
```

followed by

```
rename 's/.*([0-9]{11}_[0-9]{11}).*\.(.*$)/$1.$2/' *.ext
```

but this would make copies first and only then figured out whether the files already exist or not. I need sort of a reversed process...

EDIT:

Well, I guess this is scripting, but I finally suceeded with something like:

```
for i in /source/*.ext; do if [[ "$i" =~ [0-9]{11}_[0-9]{11} ]]; then cp $i /target/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}.ext; fi done;
```

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question if you've managed to solve the problem on your own. Use the `Answer your question` button for that (you may have to wait a few hours to give others a chance), don't put the answer in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html) can copy and rename all at once.

```
pax -rw -pp -k \
    -s'!^source/[^/]*\([0-9]\{11\}_[0-9]\{11\}\)[^/]*\(\.[^./]*\)!\1\2!' \
    -s'!.*!!' source target
```

`pax -rw` copies files; `-pp` preserves permissions, and `-k` says not to overwrite existing files. The `-s` arguments tell pax to rename files as it's copying. The first transformation makes the renaming you want (using [basic regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) and [substitutions like in `ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ed.html#tag_04_42_13_25)). The second transformation turns every source file name that's not yet matched into the empty string, which tells pax not to copy that file.

<sub>Note to zsh fans: as far as I can tell, you can't get `zmv` to copy the files where the definition doesn't exist and leave the others alone.</sub>

Comment: btw, `mmv` looks like an alternative at the first glance - it supports back references and stuff, but unfortunately only globing and no regular expressions.